# Array to table in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Help me with some problem. I am new in PS and
i need output data to table view.
Looks like this.

```
name1  name2 
-----  ----- 
value1 value2
```

But i have:

```
$a=(get-service).name
$b=(get-service).Status
foreach ($name in $a)
{

$data = [pscustomobject]@{name1 = $name}
}
$data
```

RESULT

```
name1        
-----        
XboxNetApiSvc
```

WITHOUT FOREATCH

```
$a=(get-service).name
$b=(get-service).Status


$data = [pscustomobject]@{name1 = $a ; name2 = $b }

$data
```

Result

```
name1                                                                               name2                                  
-----                                                                               -----                                  
{2GISUpdateService, AcronisActiveProtectionService, AcrSch2Svc, AdobeARMservice...} {Stopped, Running, Running, Running...}
```

All of that i need for this script

```
$list = ((Get-ADComputer   -SearchBase "OU=PC,DC=cbu,DC=lan" -Filter  {Enabled -eq "True" }  -Properties DNSHostName).DNSHostName) 
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$up = @()
$down = @()
$table= @()
foreach ($pc in $list) 
{
if ((Test-Connection -Count 1  -computer $pc -quiet) -eq $True)
 {
  $up += $pc
  #write-host $pc  "is up"

 }
 else
 {
 $down += $pc
 #Write-Host $pc "down"
 }
 }
```

After all i need output values of $up and $down in 2 columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a custom commandlet but you can run something similar to:

```
(Get-Service) | select Name,Status | Format-Table
```

**UPDATE**

After reading your update. At the end of your script you have two arrays `$up` and `$down`. I will declare it the static way to make an example easier

```
$up = @('pc1', 'pc2')
$down = @('pc3','pc4', 'pc5')
```

Because arrays can be diffrent length you need to calculate maximum length with:

```
$max = ($up, $down | Measure-Object -Maximum -Property Count).Maximum
```

And than create an object which "merges" above arrays with:

```
0..$max | Select-Object @{n="Up";e={$up[$_]}}, @{n="Down";e={$down[$_]}}
```

The output is:

```
Up  Down
--  ----
pc1 pc3
pc2 pc4
    pc5
```

Comment: @MikeNuzhdin after reading your update I wrote a solution for you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Get-Service` as example only then, you can just use `Select` :

```
Get-Service | Select Name, Status
```

Else

```
$MyList | Select Name1, Name2
```

Moreover, if you have a complex command and you want to extract a table of `PSObject` :

```
Get-Process | Select-Object -Property ProcessName, Id, WS
```

Read more about `Select-Object` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-4.0

Answer (score 0):

Yes Piotr Stapp is rights. You can use Format-Table

Example 1:

Get-Process | Sort-Object starttime | Format-Table -View starttime

Example 2:

(Get-Service) | select Name,Status | Format-Table

Example 3:

Get-Process | FT